# SwiftUI Picker in Forms (iOS 16)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Before iOS 16 picker views take on special behavior when inside forms. They looked like a navigation link which takes you to a new screen where you can choose an option.
Since iOS 16 it seems, that this behavior was removed.

Is there a possibility to get the "old" behavior?

e.g. this code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedValue = "One"
    let counts = ["One", "Two", "Three"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Picker("Selection", selection: $selectedValue) {
                        ForEach(counts, id: \.self) {
                            Text($0)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

results in this behavior (since iOS 16)

[image: picker iOS 16]

instead of this (before iOS 16)

[image: Picker Style in Forms before iOS 16]

[image: Picker Style in Forms before iOS 16]

Thanks!!!

Comment: Great that the old behavior that was available in iOS 15, is no longer available unless you change the deployment target to iOS 16!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

iOS 16 added `NavigationLinkPickerStyle` which has the pre iOS 16 behavior.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedValue = "One"
    let counts = ["One", "Two", "Three"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
                        Picker("Selection", selection: $selectedValue) {
                            ForEach(counts, id: \.self) {
                                Text($0)
                            }
                        }
                        .pickerStyle(.navigationLink)
                    } else {
                        Picker("Selection", selection: $selectedValue) {
                            ForEach(counts, id: \.self) {
                                Text($0)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's giving an error `Type "PickerStyle" has no member "navigationLink" `

Comment: it's the same for me. I get the same error, although I have set everything to iOS 16.

Comment: It's weird, because [it's in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/pickerstyle/navigationlink) 

Comment: I figured out, that `.navigationLink` was added in one of the Xcode 14.1 Betas. I'm currently using 14.1 Beta 3 :/

Comment: You're right. With 14.1 Beta 3 `.navigationLink` is available.

Comment: It is working in simulator but not in the phone (iOS 16.4) when if #available is not used..

Comment: @Mikrasya I just tested it on 16.4.1 and it's working as expected without `if #available`

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar boat, I'm currently downloading the 14.1 Beta of Xcode, however it WOULD be nice if you could have the menu style picker but also have it display nothing. It's almost as if you already have something selected, but you don't. It causes confusion with the user.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to StackOverflow. Your input is helpful but would work better as a comment. Once you get to 50 reputation, you'll be able to make comments. For now, save answers for giving tested, concrete solutions. You can learn more about writing good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).